# client X, Y not giving the correct position of a mouse

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

im currently working on a project and im trying to make a component to move exactly as where the mouse move and it doesnt returns different place everytime it moves, heres my code:

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
        const mousePos = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
        const infoElement = document.getElementById('info');
        infoElement.style.top = mousePos.y + "px";
        infoElement.style.left = mousePos.x + "px";
      });
```

heres what happen:
[image]

is there any fix to this?

Comment: I created [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/g3jp4so9/) using your code but it does not have this problem.  There must be more to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to continuously update the position of the element as the mouse moves.

```
// Get the info element
const infoElement = document.getElementById('info');

// Function to update position
function updatePosition(event) {
  const mousePos = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
  infoElement.style.top = mousePos.y + "px";
  infoElement.style.left = mousePos.x + "px";
}

// Add event listener for mousemove
window.addEventListener('mousemove', updatePosition);

// Function to update position continuously
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  // Update position here if needed
}

// Start the animation loop
animate();
```